# Alt-Tab behaviour in KDE 4.8.2 after upgrade to 12.04

Tags: 12.04, kde, window-manager, kde4

This may be a silly question for this community (and if this question does not belong here, please let know, and I'll either delete it or move to another suggested forum.)

I run Kubuntu, and I just upgraded from 11.10 to 12.04 (precise).  I am not sure which version of KDE I was running in 11.10, but I didn't really do anything except install recommended upgrades on my machine since I installed 11.10.

My question is about the Alt-Tab behavior in the (new?) version of KDE that came with 12.04.  Previously when I pressed Alt-Tab, a grid of small icons corresponding to the windows I had open on the desktop I was currently on was displayed, with the window in focus highlighted.  Now I get just one row of large icons on a fat "tape" with about 5 and a half of them fitting on the screen at a time (and I've got a 1920x1080 pixel screen!), the rest being invisible off the screen.  I usually have more than 5 windows open, and I would like to be able to see the icons for the whole set of them.  However, I have not been able to do this.

I've been to System Settings->Window Behavior->Task Switcher->Main tab and played around with that to no avail.  Is there another place I can look?  Thank you for any help!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can choose from several different styles for task switching in KDE 4.8. Refer to the first [screenshot](http://www.kde.org/announcements/4.8/plasma.php). In a nutshell, the Wrench button of "Layout based switcher" allows you to customize how to display windows when pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd>.